# My Samsung Galaxy trend plus wifi wont turn on

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth

I recently bought a Samsung Galaxy trend plus and and my wifi wont turn on evey time i try to turn it on it says turning on for abit and then turns off or a second and then says turning on again but it never actually turns on. Can anyone please help me im having the same problem with my bluetooth as well. I tried the factory reset already and it didn't work anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

## Do you have applied any update(custom or OTA) ?

Custom: If you have upgraded your ROM before official release, high possibilites are there to face these type of problems.

OTA: Very rare but possible if your manufacturer provides an OTA and this problem is occurring after updation of device.

Solution:

• If you think it is occuring after update, you should degrade your Firmware version by custom ROM.

## You have not updated device since a long time ?

In this case high possibilites of facing such problems.

Solution is please go to nearby custmore care or look for OTA update in you handset *Software Update* section which falls under *About Phone* .

[If your device is out of warranty and don't want to spend bucks on it now, please upgrade by custom ROM.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few ways to fix this, but the easiest way is to format your tablet THIS WILL DELETE EVERYTHING SO **BACK UP**:
**Go into settings (Click home button, Go into app drawer and open click on settings)
Click on Backup & Reset, then click on 'Factory data reset'
Follow the instructions to reset your tablet
[More Detailed Instructions](http://www.wikihow.com/Reformat-Android-Phones)**

Comment: I did the factory reset and it didn't work the wifi and bluetooth still won't turn on

Comment: Well then that means that there is a problem with the device, Your best off replacing it because to fix it would require rooting it, which could possibly make even more of a mess. If my answer helped you please tick it